# Hotel Bookings Possible C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, data-structures

Hotel Bookings Possible C++ from InterviewBit website. I've been working on it and I couldnt find a solution for it.
**The question is:**
A hotel manager has to process N advance bookings of rooms for the next season. His hotel has C rooms. Bookings contain an arrival date and a departure date. He wants to find out whether there are enough rooms in the hotel to satisfy the demand. Write a program that solves this problem in time O(N log N) .

**Input Format**
First argument is an integer array A containing arrival time of booking.

Second argument is an integer array B containing departure time of booking.

Third argument is an integer C denoting the count of rooms.

**Output Format**
Return True if there are enough rooms for N bookings else return False.

Return 0/1 for C programs.

**Code:**

```
bool Solution::hotel(vector<int> &arrive, vector<int> &depart, int K) {
     vector<pair<int,int> >v;
    int n=arrive.size();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        v.push_back(make_pair(arrive[i],1));
        v.push_back(make_pair(depart[i],-1));
    }
    sort(v.begin(),v.end());
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<2*n;i++){
        count+=v[i].second;
        if(count>K)
         return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and Im getting error for just this test case

```
Your submission failed for the following input
A : [ 1, 2, 3 ]
B : [ 2, 3, 4 ]
C : 1

The expected return value: 
0
Your function returned the following: 
1
```

Someone help!

Comment: The question is poorly specified and doesn't specify whether people can arrive on the same day as someone else departing (which in a real hotel you would expect to be possible) but their test case looks like they don't allow that

Comment: If there is a departure day value of `d`, does that imply the room is also available for another booking on day `d`. Or does the room become available on `d+1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're processing departures before arrivals.

In the sample test case, someone stays from days `1~2`. That means, the room is occupied on day 2; and is only vacated on day 3. For some departure date `x`, you should process it on `x+1` as that's when the guest leaves.

So, you can simply update this loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        v.push_back(make_pair(arrive[i],1));
        v.push_back(make_pair(depart[i],-1));
}
```

to:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        v.push_back(make_pair(arrive[i],1));
        v.push_back(make_pair(depart[i]+1,-1));
}
```